# Why does Maven fail to run this build run?

Tags: maven, firebase

When going trough the tutorial *[Build an Android App Using Firebase and the App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible)* I get an Apache Maven 3.3.9`Exception` which I cannot resolve.

In the tutorial one must run the

> firebase-appengine-backend

sample, and that is the cause of my problem.

Here is the `Exception`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.90.v20151210:run (default-cli) on project backend: Execution error: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error: cannot execute gcloud command java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python.exe": CreateProcess error=2, Det går inte att hitta filen -> [Help 1]org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.90.v20151210:run (default-cli) on project backend: Execution error: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error: cannot execute gcloud command java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python.exe": CreateProcess error=2, Det går inte att hitta filen
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Execution error: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error: cannot execute gcloud command java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python.exe": CreateProcess error=2, Det går inte att hitta filen
    at com.google.appengine.gcloudapp.GCloudAppRun.execute(GCloudAppRun.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more[ERROR][ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

It says that it cannot run Pyton.exe, but I have the

> C:\Users\sven\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk

It installed correctly and Pyton is there also. Also, I run a CMD as an administrator.

How do I resolve this and run the following?

> firebase-appengine-backend sample

Answer (score 0):

I did resolve the issue by using the Google Cloud SDK Shell instead of the Windows 10 CMD window.

I installed the cloud SDK to:

> C:\GoogleCloudSDK\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk

and running it like this:

> mvn gcloud:run -Dgcloud.gcloud_directory="C:\GoogleCloudSDK\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk"

But that gave another error:

> python.exe: can't open file 'C:\GoogleCloudSDK\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

The **google_appengine** folder does not exist under the **platform** folder?

The dev_appserver.py is located in:

```
C:\GoogleCloudSDK\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin
```

**gcloud info**:

```
Google Cloud SDK 124.0.0
bq 2.0.24
bq-win 2.0.24
bundled-python 2.7.10
core 2016.08.29
core-win 2016.08.05
gcloud
gsutil 4.21
gsutil-win 4.20
powershell 0.1.5
windows-ssh-tools 2016.05.13
```